# File counts not adding up: finding files ls -a misses

Tags: command-line

[Filelight](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/filelight.1.html) alleges that I have 112,028 files in my home directory, on the first level (not recursing).
 But: `ls -1a ~ | wc -l`  thinks I have 225. `find ~ -maxdepth 1 | wc -l` says 224. 
The difference comes from ls's totals header.

Where did the other 111,804 files come from?

So to search further, I found the recursive totals, but I found they were pretty close, within 111k.

- `find ~ | wc -l`: 572,152
- filelight: 569,320

Originally I thought so many unaccounted for files might indicate a rootkit, but chkrootkit only finds suckit, which is only on account of a bug.

How might I find these mysterious files? Do they really exist?

Comment: Is it possible that it follows symbolic and/or static links and counts the files under those links as well maybe? Or if the links stay within the home folder maybe it counts the files twice

Comment: What is the number of subdirectories in your home directory, either on the first level or in total?  Any symbolic links at the first level?

Comment: There are no symbolic links on the first level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Filelight, but it sounds like it might be an issue in that software.

Particularly, if you have a lot of hard links in your filesystem, filelight will read them as if they are duplicate files, which can greatly inflate both the *number* and *size* count.

See here for more info: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=144948

You may have a lot of hard links if you use some backup software, for example.

That said, 111,804 vs 225 is a big difference.  And I can't see how it would explain why the recursive counts are OK.

Comment: I ran a few commands to count the inodes vs links. Hard links must be what made the difference. I'll admit though I still don't know why the recursive counts almost matched.